# How to give color to a particular series in angular chartjs

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using ng2-charts in angular 5 for displaying line charts. On a single chart, there can be multiple lines, in order to identify a particular series
I want to assign fix color(red) to that all the time. Rest of the series can be of any color.
Currently, I use this, but this doesn't work based on [this](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/line-color/). Same way lineDashType also doesn't work.

In app.component.ts

```
   Data = array of values []
   Series is passed to datasets
   Series.push({ data: Data, fill: false, lineDashType: "solid", lineColor: "red", label: "labelname" });
```

In app.html

```
      <canvas baseChart width="1000px" height="200px"
      [datasets]="Series"
      [labels]="Dates"
      [options]="lineChartOptions"
      [legend]="lineChartLegend"
      [chartType]="lineChartType"></canvas>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle or something comparable would be really nice to help you. Also your link points to a completely wrong library. Since you are using ng2-charts (based on chart.js) you need this one http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

Comment: Your link in the comment helped! Thanks!